# Update certain data in SQL with JSP

Tags: sql, jsp

i've been learning web programming (JSP and SQL) for the past few days, i need help with certain problem, so i need to show the list of all name of members from my database, add button beside it, and when i click it, i need to update the data in database, which name is exactly the same name besides the button .

I have successfully show the data and button, and i know syntax for updating in SQL, but i have no idea how to validate when i click the button, it updates the data with the same name exactly besides the button. Let's just pretend all name is unique. This is my sample code:

```
<div id="textArea">
      <%
    String query = "SELECT * FROM member";
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next()){%>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td><%out.print(rs.getString("Fullname"));%></td>
            <td> <input type="button" value="Change Role"/> </td>

        </tr>
        </table>
    <%  
    }
    %>
</div>
```

Any help is really appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to write Java code in a JSP Page for updating certain data from JSP.

You can write Java Code inside a scriptlet in a JSP page.

You have to write scriptlet inside `<% ...%>` tag, Please see sample below:

```
<%
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
  Statement st=con.createStatement();
 ......
%>
```

Please follow the post below to execute update query directly from JSP:

[Jsp sql update query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822879/jsp-sql-update-query)